# Spring boot Unit test about best practics and currectli writing tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, spring-boot-test

I want start write unit test in my project. I tried make this many times. And he always quit, because he could not understand the meaning. because I can not find and form knowledge into a single whole. I read many articles, saw many examples, and they are all different. As a result, I understand why I need write tests, I understand how to write them, but I do not understand how correctly. And I do not understand how to write them so that they are useful. I have some questions:

For example I have service:

```
@Service
public class HumanServiceImpl implements HumanService {

  private final HumanRepository humanRepository;

  @Autowired
  public HumanServiceImpl(HumanRepository humanRepository) {
    this.humanRepository = humanRepository;
  }

  @Override
  public Human getOneHumanById(Long id) {
    return humanRepository.getOne(id);
  }

  @Override
  public Human getOneHumanByName(String firstName) {
    return humanRepository.findOneByFirstName(firstName);
  }

  @Override
  public Human getOneHumanRandom() {
    Human human = new Human();
    human.setId(Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(new Random(100))));
    human.setFirstName("firstName"+ System.currentTimeMillis());
    human.setLastName("LastName"+ System.currentTimeMillis());
    human.setAge(12);//any logic for create Human
    return human;
  }
}
```

And I tried write Unit test for this service:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class HumanServiceImplTest {

  @MockBean(name="mokHumanRepository")
  private HumanRepository humanRepository;

  @MockBean(name = "mockHumanService")
  private HumanService humanService;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    Human human = new Human();
    human.setId(1L);
    human.setFirstName("Bill");
    human.setLastName("Gates");
    human.setAge(50);

    when(humanRepository.getOne(1L)).thenReturn(human);
    when(humanRepository.findOneByFirstName("Bill")).thenReturn(human);
  }

  @Test
  public void getOneHumanById() {
    Human found = humanService.getOneHumanById(1L);
    assertThat(found.getFirstName()).isEqualTo("Bill");
  }

  @Test
  public void getOneHumanByName() {
    Human found = humanService.getOneHumanByName("Bill");
    assertThat(found.getFirstName()).isEqualTo("Bill");
  }

  @Test
  public void getOneHumanRandom() {
    //???
  }
}
```

I have questions:

**1. Where should I fill the objects? I saw different implementations**

in `@Before` like in my example, in `@Test`, mix implementations - when Human create in `@Before` and expression

```
when(humanRepository.getOne(1L)).thenReturn(human);
```

in `@Test` method

```
  private Human human;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    human = new Human();
    ...
  }

  @Test
  public void getOneHumanById() {
    when(humanRepository.getOne(1L)).thenReturn(human);
    Human found = humanService.getOneHumanById(1L);
    assertThat(found.getFirstName()).isEqualTo("Bill");
  }
```

**2. How can I test `getOneHumanRandom()` method?**

Service not use repository when call this method. I can make this method mock, but what will it give?

```
when(humanService.getOneHumanRandom()).thenReturn(human);
...
@Test
  public void getOneHumanRandom() {
    Human found = humanService.getOneHumanRandom();
    assertThat(found.getFirstName()).isEqualTo("Bill");
  }
```

I just copy the logic from the service in the test class. What is the point of such testing and is it necessary?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test rather than mocking the repository use a real implementation and test against it.

Comment: @ Darren Forsythe and for what I am an example of how to test the persistence layer, if I ask about how to test the layer of services?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Where should I fill the objects? I saw different implementations**

I would use @Before for any common setup between all / most tests. Any setup that is specific to a certain test should be go into that test method. If there is a common setup between some, but not all, of your tests you can write private setup method(s).

Remember to keep your tests / code DRY (dont repeat yourself!). Tests have a maintenance factor and keeping common code together with help alleviate some headaches in the future.

**2. How can I test getOneHumanRandom() method?**

You should create a Human toString() method. This method should concat all the properties on your Human object. You can call getOneHumanRandom() twice and assert that they are not equal.

```
@Test
public void getOneHumanRandomTest()
{
    // SETUP / TEST
    Human one = service.getOneHumanRandom();
    Human two = service.getOneHumanRandom();
    // VERIFY / ASSERT
    assertNotEquals("these two objects should not be equal", one.toString(), two.toString())
}
```

Hope this helps!